# Android native app linked to a webservice, login

Tags: android, json

I want to make a native Android application for a website.

The first problem is how to login in a website using an Android native app, (without any change on the existent webservice site), the Android app should remain connected until a click on a logout button. I have to ask about this matter and some people suggested Json.

I have downloaded JSON and GSON library and I tried to see some tutorial for login in this website with Android app with no success.

Now the access page of the website has this code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="it" dir="ltr">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">

<link rel="shortcut icon" href="templates/images/favicon.ico" />
<link rel='stylesheet' href='templates/css/base.css?1330075048' type='text/css' />
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.6.1.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/srte.js"></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src='js/jquery.form.js'></script>


<script type="text/javascript">
  var _gaq = _gaq || [];
  _gaq.push(['_setAccount', 'UA-000000000-1']);
  _gaq.push(['_setDomainName', 'domainname.it']);
  _gaq.push(['_trackPageview']);


</script>

<title>Nomes - Login</title>
</head>

<body class='login' style='background: #fff;'>
<div id="headwrapper" style='height:80px;'>
    <div id="head">
        <div class="logo" dir="ltr"><a href='http://www.domainname.it'><img src='templates/images/image.jpg'/></a></div>
        <div class='banner'><img src='templates/images/banner-head.jpg'/></div>

    </div>
</div>
<div id="theadwrapper">
    <div id="tabhead">
    </div>
</div>

<div id='background_wrapper'>
    <div id="wrapper">
        <div id="messages"></div>



                    <div><h5>Email</h5><input id='email' type='text' name='email' /></div>
                    <div><h5>Password</h5><input id='password' type='password' name='password' /></div>
                </div>
                <div class='rememberme'><input type='checkbox' name='remember' id='remember_me'>Ricordami</div>
                <div class='submit'>
                    <button type='submit' name='post' class='medium green'>Accedi</button><br/>
                    <p>o <a href='register.php'>Iscriviti</a></p>

                </div>
            </form>
            <div id='reset_pass'>Hai dimenticato la password? Clicca <a href='resetpwd.php'>qui</a></div>
            </div>
            <div class='advert'>
                <br/><br/><img src='templates/images/sfumatura-orizzontale.jpg' />
                <div class='circles'></div>
            </div>

        <script>
        $(document).ready(function(){
            $('#login_form').submit(function(e){
                e.preventDefault();
                if ( ($('#login_form #email').val() == "") 
                  || ($('#login_form #password').val() == "") ) return;
                $('#login_form').attr("disabled", "disabled").css({opacity:0.5});
                $(this).ajaxSubmit({
                    dataType: "json",
                    success: function(data) {
                        if (data.isError) {
                            Bore.error(data.errorMessage);
                            $('#login_form').removeAttr("disabled").css({opacity:1});
                        }
                        else {

                                                            window.location.replace(data.data.defaultPage);
                                                        }
                    },
                    error: function() {
                        $('#login_form').removeAttr("disabled").css({opacity:1});
                        console.log('error');
                    }
                });
            });
        });
        </script>
        <div class='circle'></div>
        </div><!-- login_content -->
        <div style='clear:both; padding: 10px;'></div>
    </div><!-- wrapper -->
</div> <!-- bg_rapper -->
```

Comment: You can not build a native app without any changes at the server end. you can still make a post request and log in but i can't think of any such use case. Is your website at least mobile optimized?

Comment: This site has yet an iPhone native app that use json rpc to comunicate with the server.

Comment: In that case you should know the parameters your server accepts. Can be more detailed if you can tell the website address. In case you can't, then try to find out the parameters it takes and response it returns while logging in from the browser. If you're using CHrome then press F12 and go to Network tab. you must be able to see the ajax requests it is making.

Comment: Thank you for the answer.

The website address is http://www.condomani.it the login page is http://app.condomani.it/login.php.

Comment: I cannot understand how to parse parameters and call function of the website in android :(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should access the server interface with the parameters that your server accepts.

Access the site parsing the PHP and using the nested function in the PHP code, is a really bad idea.